# Pandas merge is slow on huge dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have 4 pandas dataframes(each 32 millions rows) . I want to concatenate those dataframes in such a way that the merged dataframes has only new variables added from all the dataframes.

For example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'col1' : [1, 2, 3],
                           'col2' : [10, 11, 12], 'col3' : [1, 1, 2], 'col4' : [100, 200, 300]})

df1

   col1  col2  col3  col4
0     1    10     1   100
1     2    11     1   200
2     3    12     2   300

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'col1' : [1, 2, 3],
                           'col2' : [10, 11, 12], 'col3' : [1, 1, 2], 'col5' : [20, 40, 60]})

   col1  col2  col3  col5
0     1    10     1    20
1     2    11     1    40
2     3    12     2    60

df3 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'col1' : [1, 2, 3],
                           'col2' : [10, 11, 12], 'col3' : [1, 1, 2], 'col6' : [90, 100, 110]})

   col1  col2  col3  col6
0     1    10     1    90
1     2    11     1    100
2     3    12     2    100
```

My expected output dataframe:

```
   col1  col2  col3   col4  col5 col6
0     1    10     1  100.0   20   90
1     2    11     1  200.0   40   100
2     3    12     2  300.0   60   110
```

I tried the below code, and it works perfectly fine but it is very slow (since my dataframes are huge)

```
df_merge=df1.merge(df2.merge(df3))
print(df_merge)

   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6
0     1    10     1   100    20   90
1     2    11     1   200    40   100
2     3    12     2   300    60   110
```

Is there any efficient way of doing the same.

Comment: Are you merging on index?

Comment: 32 millions rows...why not try pyspark

Comment: @YO and BEN_W That is not an option.

Comment: @HenryYik I guess ```df_merge=df1.merge(df2.merge(df3))``` merges on index

Comment: Then can't you just assign the news rows like `df["col5"] = df2["col5"]` if there is no lookup required?

Comment: why can't you use pyspark i'd use that or dask, 32million is too big for pandas.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is worthy but I have heard about `modin`, which is a pandas for big datasets:
https://github.com/modin-project/modin